# mongodb bucket boundaries greater than query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have mongodb bucket query to get lowerbound and upperbound counts. Now I want greater than query to display discount for > 10%, > 20%, >50%, >60% etc.

i dont know how to include grater than in boundaries. or using any other way to get count for the offers?

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate([{$facet: {
"offers":[{$unwind:"$variants"},
{$match:{"variants.prices.discount_percent": { $exists: 1 }, 
"variants.is_published":{"$ne":false}}},
{
      $bucket: {
        groupBy: "$variants.prices.discount_percent",
        boundaries: [  0, 20, 30, 40, 100,Infinity ],

        output: {
          "count": { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }      }
  ]}}

  ])
```

what I want in this case is total count for discount. so 20% discount includes discount of 30% above, 30% includes 40% above so on..

output should be:

20% - (10), 
30% - (5), 
40% - (2) etc..

here 20% count is 10 which includes 5 and 2 as well. because its >= 20. 30% includes count 2 of 40% because its >= 30.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking or even expecting. You *could* show an example, **but** the whole point of a **boundary** is basically that **everything** appearing in the *next boundary* is ***greater than*** the previous one. Also I note here an extremely pointless use of `$facet` with only a single output key. Whilst generally okay with something like `$bucket` and a defined number of output keys meaning a very small output should be obtained, this really should not be overused. BSON documents have a size limit, where as a Cursor does not.

Comment: @NeilLunn, this is just example. I have multiple facet in query. what I want in this case is total count for discount. so 20% discount includes discount of 30% above, 30% includes 40% above so on.. 

20% - (10),
30% - (5),
40% - (2)  etc..
here 20% count is 10 which includes 5 and 2 as well. because its > 20. 30% includes count 2 of 40% because its > 30/

Comment: **Not clear what you are asking**. Read the comment again and please **edit the question** with the specific details it actually asks you do add.

Comment: @NeilLunn edited question and comment.